# Redirect_to path_url append query string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I am new to Ruby Rails. I am redirecting my page to `/user/locations` using `redirect_to user_locations_url` and I want to append a query string like `?code='value'` which makes it like `user_locations_url?code='value'`.

How do i use it with redirect_to to pass query string parameters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do `redirect_to user_locations_url(code: 'value')`

Comment: Thank you! But I tried this. But gives me rails error with syntax. And does not redirect to the mentioned URL